# discord.js How to revoke a ban of a banned user using code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js

### Revoking A Ban Using Code

So, I am making a moderation discord bot using VS Code and I have already set up a ban command. I want to make a unban command (revoking a ban) too so that the user can easily unban a user and not have to go into `Server Settings` to do it.

I know you can do it because I have been using another bot, GAwesomeBot, that is able to do it. 
Link to GAwesomeBot: https://gawesomebot.com

I am a little new to Stack Overflow and this is my first question so pardon me if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using GuildMemberManager#unban
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=unban

```
let guildMemberManager, toUnbanSnowflake;
guildMemberManager.unban(toUnbanSnowflake); // Takes UserResolveable as argument
```

Comment: Oh um, I think you have misunderstood, I am trying to **unban** a user from the guild after him/her being banned.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to define the user that you are unbanning.
Because the user is already banned you will have to mention the user by their ID and then unbanning them.

```js
let args = message.content.split(/ +/g); //Split the message by every space
let user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]); //getting the user
user.unban({ reason: args[2].length > 0 ? args[2] : 'No reason provided.' }); //Unbanning the user
```

The full example:

```js
//Define your variables
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var prefix = 'your-prefix-here';

//Add a message event listener
client.on('message', () => {
    let args = message.content.split(/ +/g); //Split the message by every space
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'unban') {
        let user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]); //getting the user
        if (!user) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user ID');
        user.unban({ reason: args[2].length > 0 ? args[2] : 'No reason provided.' }).then(() => message.channel.send('Success');
    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get the user when you declare `let user = ...`, it returns undefined. I think it is because the user is banned and not in the server anymore. Maybe I am wrong, pls help! I am really new here.

Comment: You need to get the user ID to unban them. If your prefix was `!` you would say in your Discord guild `!unban 123456789` the `123456789` represents the user's ID which you can get by right clicking on a user and choosing the option `copy ID`. However you must have `Discord Developer Mode` enabled from your settings.

Comment: Appreciate the help! Fixed my issue!